# Image opened with FileProvider doesn't load

Tags: java, android, file, android-fileprovider

Good morning,
I'm trying to open an image using FileProvider.
The problem is that the image is not loaded although it is present in that path and my intent correctly opens a photo viewer.

```
    String imagePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/stack.jpg";
    File file = new File(imagePath);
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
    resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri a = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
    resultIntent.setDataAndType(a, "image/*");
    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

I have included all the things necessary for Android N+ about Uri like provider paths and provider configuration in manifest.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Replace `image/*` with `image/jpeg`, since you are the one supplying the image and you know what MIME type it is. Make sure that your app holds `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, including asking for that permission at runtime. Beyond that, examine Logcat to see what error messages are being logged by the photo viewer, and write an instrumented test to confirm that outside code can access your `FileProvider`. Finally, bear in mind that your code will not work on Android Q (by default) and Android R+ (for all apps), as you do not have access to `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures`.

Comment: I have replaced the MIME type and i'm also asking READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission at runtime in onCreate method. The image still not loads. I'm on Android Pie.

Comment: "i'm also asking READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission at runtime in onCreate method" -- more importantly, you need to not try using your code from your question until after the user has granted the permission. And, again, use Logcat to see if the photo viewer is logging anything, write an instrumented test to test your code, and possibly write a scrap app that implements `ACTION_VIEW` for `image/jpeg` so you can see things from the photo viewer's perspective.

Comment: I think i have got something. Actually the image viewer is loading `content://packagename.provider/external_pictures/Pictures/MyWall.jpg`. How can i adjust it?

Comment: my provider paths configured in manifest is this one:                                       `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>`

Comment: "Actually the image viewer is loading..." -- are you sure that it has `external_pictures` and not `external_files`? You might want to log the value of `a` that you are putting into the `Intent` as well.

Comment: the a is fine. i think i'm configuring bad the provider files. How can i do that to match my desidered path?

Comment: `external-files-path` would be a closer match than `external-path`, though both should work

Comment: So, i have adjusted things. Debug mode gave me this `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyWall.jpg` and at "FileProvider.getUriFromFile..." debug mode have this: `content://thepackage.fileprovider/Pictures/MyWall.jpg`

Comment: i have also adjusted the provider paths following your tip: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="Pictures" path="Pictures/" /> 
</paths>` . The incredibile thing is that the images is still not loading.